# How do I link my Heroku Config Variables to a Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, config

I've built a simple Twitter bot using Node.js, that can be found [here](https://github.com/ajukco/100daysofcode-bot). To avoid my Twitter access tokens being on view in my public Github repository I have deleted the config.js file and instead added the tokens into Heroku within the *settings > config variables* section. I'm now struggling to 'get' or 'call' these config variables for my app.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Config Variables Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luVy8.png)

Answer (score 3):

Those configuration variables are stored in the environment for the running process: you can fetch them via `process.env` like any other environmental variable e.g. `process.env.access_token_key`.